# How to fetch data from server component, using useSearchParams to build url in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm simply trying to fetch data in Next js but facing some issues between client and server components.

```
  import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';

  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const searchValue = searchParams.get('query');
  const url = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REQUEST_URL}${searchValue}`;
```

Here I'm grabbing from searchParams necessary value for request. Since I'm using useSearchParams it's a client component.

And here is the main issue, how to fetch? I tried many ways, like creating custom hook:

```
const { data, loading, error } = useFetch(searchValue);
```

Or just simply fetching it, like this:

```
const fetchFilms = async (url) => {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  return await response.json();
}
```

But I get issue that async await can't be used in client component.

So how I should be able to de it? If I make it server component I can't grap necessary value from query params, and can't do request, in other side I can't do request.
Can you suggest something or maybe bring some materials?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you fetch normally in client components as with `useEffect` with some modifications. The important thing is that you won't be able to use them like the way you do for server components, ie:

```
export default async function Page() {
  const res = await fetch('https://...', { next: { tags: ['collection'] } })
  const data = await res.json()
  // ...
}
```

You will have to combine the fetching with `useEffect` hook and manage these data with `useState` hook for further interacting with the client componenets.

```
'use client'
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Page() {
  /* useState hook to store fetch data */
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  /* async function to fetch data */
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = fetch('https://...', { next: { tags: ['collection'] } })
    const data = await res.json()
    setData(data)
  };

  /* useEffect to call fetch function after the page is loaded */
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  

  return(
    //...
  )
}
```

Hope this can help!

Comment: I just fetch as documented, and get following error

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding `'use client'` to a module that was originally written for the server.

Comment: @GevorgMartirosyan sorry mate, I attached the `pages` router document which works differently for the `app` router. I have modified the answer to match the app router.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways ('m thinking of) in which you can do this.

First, with limited code change, you can drop async/await and `fetch(...).then(...)` in the client component.

Second is to use server action. i.e.: an `app/action.ts` like

```
'use server'
 
export async function fetchFilms(url) {
  // await ...
}
```

then use it in the client

```
'use client'
import { fetchFilms } from '@/app/actions'
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
...

useEffect(() => {
    const getFilms = async () => {
      const searchParams = useSearchParams();
      const searchValue = searchParams.get('query');
      const url = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REQUEST_URL}${searchValue}`;
      const films = await fetchFilms(url)
      // Put the films in a local state or whatever you need
    }
 
    getFilms()
  }, [])
...
```

You could fetch your external URL in the useEffect like shown above but the server action would bypass CORS issues.